# Combine multiple animations for PathView delegate

Tags: c++, qt, animation, qml, qt6

Qt 6.2.0, Ubuntu 20.04.
Here the code of my `PathView`:

```
PathView {
    id: view
    property int item_gap: 60

    anchors.fill: parent
    pathItemCount: 3
    preferredHighlightBegin: 0.5
    preferredHighlightEnd: 0.5
    highlightRangeMode: PathView.StrictlyEnforceRange
    highlightMoveDuration: 1000
    snapMode: PathView.SnapToItem
    rotation: -90

    model: modelContent
    delegate: DelegateContent { }

    path: Path {
        startX: view.width + item_gap; startY: view.height / 2
        PathAttribute { name: "iconScale"; value: 0.7 }
        PathAttribute { name: "iconOpacity"; value: 0.1 }
        PathAttribute { name: "iconOrder"; value: 0 }
        PathLine {x: view.width / 2; y: view.height / 2; }
        PathAttribute { name: "iconScale"; value: 1 }
        PathAttribute { name: "iconOpacity"; value: 1 }
        PathAttribute { name: "iconOrder"; value: 9 }
        PathLine {x: -item_gap; y: view.height / 2; }
    }
}
```

and here its delegate:

```
Item {
    id: root

    property int highlightMoveDuration: 1000
    property int image_width: 864 * 0.8

    required property int index
    required property string label
    required property string thumbnail

    width: image_width; height: width * 1.7778
    scale: PathView.iconScale
    opacity: PathView.iconOpacity
    z: PathView.iconOrder

    Image {
        id: img
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        cache: true
        asynchronous: true
        source: "file://" + thumbnail
        sourceSize: Qt.size(parent.width, parent.height)
        visible: false
        }

        // other non-relevant stuff
    }
}
```

When I receive a signal from C++ I want to animate the current item in the following way:

1. fade it and all the other items to transparent
2. *in the meantime* (i.e. at the same time the previous animation runs) the current item (only) has to move up along Y axis
3. call a C++ function
4. reposition the item at the original position (it's still transparent)
5. fade it and all the other items back to solid

I tried something like this:

```
SequentialAnimation {
    id: selectedContent
    running: false

    ParallelAnimation {
        PropertyAnimation { target: view; properties: "opacity"; duration: 500; to: 0.0}
        PropertyAnimation { target: view.delegate; properties: "y"; duration: 500; to: 0.0}
    }

    ScriptAction { script: ccp_code.selectedContent(view.currentIndex) }

    ParallelAnimation {
        PropertyAnimation { target: view; properties: "opacity"; duration: 500; to: 1.0}
        PropertyAnimation { target: view.delegate; properties: "y"; duration: 0; to: view.height / 2}
    }
}
```

but the y properties of the delegate is not found:

```
QML PropertyAnimation: Cannot animate non-existent property "y"
```

Just to check the behavior I set `target: view`, but still there is no movements on the `y` axis.

Would you please help me to understand how to achieve such an animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `view.delegate` is a `Component`, which is like a class definition, not a class instance. Your PathView may create many instances of that delegate. So you can't use `view.delegate` as a target for an animation because it needs to know which instance you're referring to.

Since it's the current item you're interested in, you can use the `currentItem` property to get the correct instance.

```
PropertyAnimation { target: view.currentItem; properties: "y"; duration: 500; to: 0.0}
```